# How to handle exception within a servant handler monad?

Tags: haskell, servant

I want to handle a database exception inside a servant handler monad.

I've tried to use the `try` function from the `Control.Exception` package to be able to case match with `Left exception -> throwError err422 { errBody = ... }`.

I'm using [postgresql-typed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-typed) to interface with a PostgreSQL database. I want to capture a [PGError](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-typed-0.5.3.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Typed-Protocol.html#t:PGError) exception.

The [relevant code](https://github.com/fernandomrtnz/secretos/blob/server-haskell-refactor/server/src/Main.hs#L57-L65) with the following modification:

```hs
accountHandler :: CreateAccountPayload -> Handler Account
accountHandler payload =
  let errors = validateCreateAccountPayload payload in
  if hasErrors errors then
    throwError err422 { errBody = JSON.encode errors }
  else
    do
      result <- try (liftIO (insertAccount payload))
      case result of
        Right account -> return account
        Left exception -> throwError err422 { errBody = JSON.encode [ValidationError (Text.pack "email") (Text.pack "is already taken")] }
```

I am expecting to be able to capture a result from the database call and be able to case match it. The cases should be for an exception or a value. I am currently getting the following compile error:

```
src/Main.hs:64:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Handler’
      Expected type: Handler (Either e0 Account)
        Actual type: IO (Either e0 Account)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        result <- try (liftIO (insertAccount payload))
      In the expression:
        do result <- try (liftIO (insertAccount payload))
           case result of
             Right account -> return account
             Left exception -> throwError err422 {errBody = encode ...}
      In the expression:
        if hasErrors errors then
            throwError err422 {errBody = encode errors}
        else
            do result <- try (liftIO (insertAccount payload))
               case result of
                 Right account -> return account
                 Left exception -> throwError ...
   |
64 |       result <- try (liftIO (insertAccount payload))
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd think that `liftIO` lifts your `IO Account` result into the `Handler` monad. If so, perhaps `try` should go first and `liftIO` second: `result <- liftIO (try (insertAccount payload))`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann That and updating the pattern match in the case to `Left (PGError e) ->` did the trick. Thanks! I'll accept that answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think that `liftIO` lifts your `IO Account` result into the `Handler` monad. If so, perhaps `try` should go first and `liftIO` second:

```
result <- liftIO (try (insertAccount payload))
case result of
    Right account -> return account
    Left (PGError e) -> throwError err422
```